# How Visitor Pattern avoid downcasting

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

can anyone show example code before and after to avoid down casting for visitor pattern code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A bare, minimalistic example.

### Before

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};

// Some arbitrary function that handles Base.
void
Handle(Base& obj) {
    if (...type is Derived1...) {
        Derived1& d1 = static_cast<Derived1&>(base);
        std::printf("Handling Derived1\n");
    }
    else if (...type is Derived2...) {
        Derived2& d2 = static_cast<Derived2&>(base);
        std::printf("Handling Derived2\n");
    }
}
```

This means `Base` must have some type tag field, or you will be using `dynamic_cast` to check for each type.

### After

```
// Class definitions
class Visitor;
class Base {
public:
    // This is for dispatching on Base's concrete type.
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) = 0;
};
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    // Any derived class that wants to participate in double dispatch
    // with visitor needs to override this function.
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v);
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v);
};
class Visitor {
public:
    // These are for dispatching on visitor's type.
    virtual void Visit(Derived1& d1) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Derived2& d2) = 0;
};

// Implementation.
void
Derived1::Accept(Visitor& v) {
    v.Visit(*this); // Calls Derived1 overload on visitor
}
void
Derived2::Accept(Visitor& v) {
    v.Visit(*this); // Calls Derived2 overload on visitor
}
```

That was the framework. Now you implement actual visitor to handle the object polymorphically.

```
// Implementing custom visitor
class Printer : public Visitor {
    virtual void Visit(Derived1& d1) { std::printf("Handling Derived1\n"); }
    virtual void Visit(Derived2& d2) { std::printf("Handling Derived2\n"); }
};

// Some arbitrary function that handles Base.
void
Handle(Base& obj)
{
    Printer p;
    obj.Accept(p);
}
```

1. `Accept()` is a virtual function that dispatches on the type of `obj` (first dispatch)
2. It then calls appropriate overload of `Visit()`, because inside `Accept()` you already know the type of your object.
3. `Visit()`, in turn, is a virtual function that dispatches on the type of visitor (second dispatch).

Because you have double dispatch (one on object, another on visitor), you don't do any casting. The downside is that any time you add a class to your hierarchy, you have to go and update your visitor class to add an appropriate function to handle the new subclass.

Comment: I understand your explanation but i wonder what is the class hierarchy for before the visitor pattern was applied in the example. 

I wonder the handle method is in base class or derived class. 

What is the typical example of derived class implementation ?

Comment: @peterwkc, I've added the class hierarchy. It's exactly the same, except without the visitor bits. `Handle()` is just an arbitrary function that goes anywhere (no matter where). Derived class which is a part of the hierarchy must implement `Accept()` and call a visitor with itself.

Comment: The last bit is IMO not a downside but an upside actually. It's usually better to be forced in compile time to update Visitor classes than to track the downcasting across dozens of if-else statements.

Answer (score 4):

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#C.2B.2B_Example) example uses double dispatch, no downcasting.