# Determining which derived class the pointer to the abstract class is set to

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, derived-class

I'm not sure if I phrased my question as well as I liked to but I'll give an example to clear things up.

Here is the code:

```
class Shape;
class Circle;
class Triangle;

class Shape
{
    Shape(void);
    ~Shape(void);

    virtual void DrawShape(void) = 0;
}

class Circle : public Shape
{
    /* .... constructor/destructor defined normally .... */
    bool TestIntersection(Triangle* _triangle);
    bool TestIntersection(Circle* _circle);
    void DrawShape(void);
}

/* main.cpp */

...
Shape* shape;
Shape* circle = new Circle;

if(a == 0)
{
    shape = new Circle;
}
else
{
    shape = new Triangle;
}

circle->TestIntersection(shape);
```

I get the error that there is no acceptable conversion from Shape* to Circle* or Triangle*.

Why is this happening? Or do I need a way to determine which derived class has been set to the abstract class pointer?

Comment: `Circle` does not derive from `Shape`.  Also `circle.` is not going to work, as `circle` is a pointer.  Please could you post some real code, to save confusion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Visitor Pattern avoid downcasting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254788/how-visitor-pattern-avoid-downcasting)

Comment: (because attempting to know what the derived type is, is the first step in downcasting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need basically is this:

- [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

I noticed that you have not derived your *supposedly* derived classes from `Shape`. Fix that also. That is, `Triangle` and `Circle` should be derived from `Shape`. After that, read about Visitor pattern, its various implementations and usage. That will help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might just be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mmm... I've read the visitor pattern and it offers a lot of inspiration on how my code should work, but it would be really helpful if someone could give me a explicit example on how to implement it for my code above. I would really appreciate that. (I've changed the code above: Circle and Triangle are derived types of Shape, I just forgot to type that bit in.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Circle` class doesn't seem to inherit from `Shape`:

Try this:

```
class Circle : Shape
{

}
```

Comment: Why is that? Shape * can definetly hold a a Circle * if Circle Inherits from Shape.

Comment: The real problem is the call to `TestIntersection`; there is no overload that takes a `Shape*`.

Comment: But his problem is in the ctor and assignement, not sure he wants to have that function. But I feel it's not the compile issue at hand.

Comment: Presumably OP would benefit from **public** inheritance here.

Comment: Yes, OP needs to fix one thing at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have actually not derived from the Shape.

```
class Circle: public Shape {
...
};
```

Comment: The problem in the title? No. But it does answer the question at the end of your problem description. As for the detecting of which derived class is it: there are many ways to solve it. One is to use typeid() and type_info, another define an abstract method in Shape class, which others must use to identify themselves (means a maintenance overhead, but less object code than the first method)

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to define this abstract method?

Comment: `virtual Kind kind() const = 0;`

Comment: `enum Kind { Circle, Triangle, Line, Point, BlackHole };`