# How can I iterate over all subclasses of a C++ class (at compile time)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, metaprogramming

I want to generate a test case which asserts that a virtual method fulfills certain properties for all subclasses. How can I automate this?

```
class A {
 virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
 virtual int foo() override;
};

class C : public A {
 virtual int foo() override;
};
```

I want to do something like (I know the syntax below is rubbish)

```
for (A : SUBCLASSES_OF(A))
{
  A a;
  assert(a.foo() == 42);
}
```

Is that even possible with boost/template meta-programming/macro magic, or am I making a huge error in reasoning here?

Comment: maybe you can hack up something with registering everything in boost fusion, but without any kind of previous registering, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

What about a vistor? See [Vistor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
Also this answer is probaly helpful [How Visitor Pattern avoid downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254788/how-visitor-pattern-avoid-downcasting).

Comment: Wouldn't that still require explicitly stating all subclasses (by providing a visit-overload)?

Comment: Yes. It is not exactly what you asked for, but probably another approach for your real problem..

Answer (score 2):

That is impossible to do. Consider that the set of classes that extend a given base will probably be unknown when you compile the code you want. In particular, there nothing that blocks you or any other developer from adding a new class after your translation unit is compiled, and now 'compile time' of your translation and 'compile time' for your whole project would be different times.

The better question is *what do you really want to solve?*

Comment: I was hoping that for better test coverage, **any** subclass could automatically be found and a test case generated (in case someone subclasses A, implements foo() and forgets to test it). 
So manually adding it should be avoided, but every subclass automatically registering itself somewhere would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think workable solution could be to write a script (for example in python) that scans your directory(es) and generate C++ source code with test cases for you. I do not think there is a way to do that in c++ itself (without using nonstandard extensions that could be provided by particular compiler/platform).

Answer (score 0):

Would http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Running.html help? I know a colleague use to use it years ago for generating code.

I've also known people to leverage the Xml output from Doxygen.